# Integrating PlayN Html compilation with SSL

Tags: javascript, facebook, ssl, playn

I built a cross platform application using Google's PlayN framework and was able to get the application running over html5/javascript using a standard webpage. I wanted to integrate this in as a Facebook application, but Facebook is blocking the actual application itself from running, claiming that the application is failing to use SSL in all circumstances (A requirement for Facebook applications). Is there a compilation switch or setting that would force it to run over SSL? I have the application running in Google App Engine with SSL enabled, but the application itself seems to be compiled to use HTTP calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure jetty to expose application through https.
Look at [jetty-maven-docs](http://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html)